# What is the mean of '*' when use 'from math import *'

Tags: python, math, import, sqrt

i made a code like this. and i learned`import *`calling all module in math
but i don't know mean of '*'
the result is diffrent with the thing i think

i thinked answer of '`d*e`' is 16
also, answer of '`d**e`' is 64
and so, `sqrt(d**e)` will be 8

i searched google but i don know the mean of *

```
d = 8
e = 2

from math import *

print(d*e)
print(d**e)
sqrt(d ** e)
```

but, result was 16.88210319127114

what is the mean of '*' ??

Comment: Your confusion comes from e being overwritten with Euler's constant when you imported math.

Comment: And that's why the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#imports) says: "Wildcard imports (`from <module> import *`) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools.". Here we have a wonderful example where this happenss.

Answer (score 1):

`*` is a wildcard that loads all of the functions in that library into your local namespace.